# Difference between cl_context & cl::Context

Tags: c++, buffer, opencl

I was trying to create a Buffer for my OpenCL program. However, the function

```
clCreateBuffer
```

expects a `cl_context` instead of the one I am using, which is `cl::Context`.
What ways are there around this, and or what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing the OpenCL C API (`clCreateBuffer`) with the C++ API (`cl::Context`). Don't do this and stick to either C or C++.

If you already have a `cl::Context`, then you should stick with the C++ API. The corresponding call to create a buffer, e.g., for 100 floats would be:

```
cl::Context context(...); // your context creation
cl_int err;
cl::Buffer my_buffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(cl_float)*100, NULL, &err); 
if (err != CL_SUCCESS) {
    std::cerr << "ERROR: create buffer (" << err << ")" << std::endl;
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: *That*'s a C++ API? Oh dear.

Answer (score 3):

`cl_context` is the low-level type of an OpenCL context (from cl.h), whereas `cl::Context` is from the OpenCL C++ wrapper (cl.hpp). To get the `cl_context` from an object of type `cl::Context` use `operator()`. For example if your context variable was "foo", to pass it to `clCreateBuffer` use `clCreateBuffer(foo(), flags, ...)`.

I have found you are better off using either the C API or the C++ wrappers but not both together because it gets confusing and/or tedious to convert between them. Also beware the reference counting when constructing C++ wrappers from the low-level types.